# How do you decrease the window size of the gmapInfoWindow in primefaces?

Tags: html, css, jsf-2, primefaces

How do you decrease the window size of the gmapInfoWindow in primefaces?

Based on what I am seeing, maxWidth does not work at all as I set it to 50 for 50px but the window is always 247px in size.

Is there a way to change it?

Here is the div tag straight from chrome:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 247px; height: 88px; overflow: hidden; -webkit-user-select: none; background-color: white; border: 1px solid rgb(171, 171, 171); "></div>
```

Here is the gmapInfoWindowCode for a gmap:

```
<p:gmap>
    <p:gmapInfoWindow id="infoWindow">
                <table border="0" padding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr class="custom-header-tr"><td><h:outputText value="#{mapBean.marker.data.name}"/></td></tr>
                    <tr class="custom-tr"><td class="custom-td"><p:commandLink action="#{mapBean.marker.data.ping()}" styleClass="custom-link" update="infoMessages">Ping Device</p:commandLink></td></tr>
                    <tr class="custom-tr"><td class="custom-td"><p:commandLink action="#{mapBean.marker.data.syncToDevice()}" styleClass="custom-link" update="infoMessages">Sync to Device</p:commandLink></td></tr>
                    <tr class="custom-tr"><td class="custom-td"><p:commandLink action="#{mapBean.marker.data.syncFromDevice()}" styleClass="custom-link" update="infoMessages">Sync from Device</p:commandLink></td></tr>
                    <tr class="custom-tr"><td class="custom-td"><p:commandLink action="#{mapBean.marker.data.checkSync()}" styleClass="custom-link" update="infoMessages">Check Sync</p:commandLink></td></tr>
                </table> 
            </p:gmapInfoWindow>
        </p:gmap>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what do you mean by gmapInfoWindow? the gmap component?

Comment: Hi Ravi, I looked at your image and it shows a div tag without an id attribute and with an inline style with a set width.  My problem is that I don't know how to get that div tag and change its width programmatically in JavaScript since the div tag has no id value.